# Obtener una fecha con formato 'YYYY-MM-DD' en JavaScript a partir de un Datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Buenas. Tengo un ***Datetime picker*** en un formulario para seleccionar una fecha y necesito que al hacerlo se le sumen 30 días y el resultado aparezca en un **input** con formato 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Capturo el valor en el *evento 'onChange'* del ***Datetime picker***. El problema viene al sumarle la cantidad indicada y obtener la fecha en el formato requerido.

```js
$('.datepicker-only-init').datetimepicker({
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        console.log(e.date);
 });
```

Un **cosole.log** de la fecha devuelve este formato:

> Wed May 31 2017 10:12:02 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ejemplo para la fecha:

```
var deadline = new Date();
console.log(deadline);
//Wed May 31 2017 12:23:16 GMT-0500 (Hora de verano central (México))
var x = new Date(deadline.setDate(deadline.getDate() + 30));
console.log(x);
//Fri Jun 30 2017 12:23:16 GMT-0500 (Hora de verano central (México))
```

Asumiendo que el objeto "e.date" es de tipo fecha quedaría algo así:

```
var x = new Date(e.date.setDate(e.date.getDate() + 30));
console.log(x);
```

Comment: me da el  error Uncaught TypeError: e.date.getDate() is not a function, la idea es según la fecha que seleccione sumarle 30 días y que me devuelva la nueva fecha en este formato 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: Podrias darle un: console.log(e), para ver que tipo de dato es "e" o puedes poner el codigo en un https://jsfiddle.net/ y compartirlo

Comment: Ok ya vi que el tipo es "moment"
el valor de la fecha esta en: `e.date._d`. Quedaría entonces así: `var x = new Date(e.date._d.setDate(e.date._d.getDate() + 30));` `console.log(x);`

Comment: muy bien ya me bota la fecha, en este formato: Sat Jun 10 2017 14:53:59 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica),como puedo pasarlo a 2017-05-10

Comment: con moment `console.log(moment(x).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));`

Answer (score 1):

Creo que de esta manera estará solucionado tu problema

```js
$('.datepicker-only-init').datetimepicker({
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}).on('dp.change', function (e) {
       console.log(e.date.setDate(e.date.getDate() + 30));
 });
```

Comment: tengo el siguiente error en consola: Uncaught TypeError: e.date.addDays is not a function

Comment: Disculpa, creo que esto te funcionará


console.log(e.date.setDate(e.date.getDate() + 30));

Comment: :( el mismo error

Comment: Si e es de tipo date puedes hacer esto :

console.log(e.setDate(e.getDate() + 30));